What is this sketch by Rowan Atkinson?
I remember seeing this skit on the TV sometime during the 90's (the actual skit might (or might not) be older, it was not a stage show, and it was not Mr. Bean).
It was a short funny sketch by Rowan Atkinson, one main supporting actor (who played Atkinson's character's assistant or something) and other actors who only appear briefly.    
I only watched the show from the middle so I don't know much about its story and what I remember about it is a bit fuzzy.
The setting was medieval England and Atkinson was expecting a visit from the Queen later on in the day, but he did not know what the Queen looked like (I think it was something like that from what I remember).
Atkinson in reality was a mean, greedy miserly character (and his assistant knew about this side of him) but somehow he had gained a reputation for being a very nice person, and the Queen was coming to his house to give him an award for being the nicest person in their area.
The assistant was supposed to tell Atkinson when the Queen arrived so that he could start acting nice in front of her, but due to some reason (Atkinson sending the assistant to an errand or something) the assistant is not around when the Queen actually meets him, and Atkinson then starts insulting her about how fat, old and ugly she is.
After all the insults are finished the assistant shows up and informs Atkinson that that woman was the Queen, and the program ends there.    
This is as much as I remember. I have never seen this program again and I have gone through Wikipedia's list of skits by Rowan Atkinson but nothing rings a bell. Please bear in mind that I might have got some details wrong (like the woman might not have been the Queen, but she was definitely a Royal or a nobleman).  
Could someone help me identify what the name of this skit was?  
For those who might find this helpful:
Wikipedia's list of television appearances by Rowan Atkinson
Wikipedia's list of film appearances by Rowan Atkinson

And you're certain it wasn't a scene from Blackadder?

Blackadder came to my mind too, though I thought first of The Queen of Spain's Beard in which he's going to marry the Spanish Infanta (not get an award from her), but that also doesn't end when they meet.

I've never seen Blackadder but it didn't look like it was an episode of a longer running show, it seemed more like a one-off sketch

It sounds like Beer episode from Blackadder 2, but the key features of that episode is the wearing of fake boobs by all the men and a turnip in the shape of a thingy

Sounds like Blackadder to me.
The plot of
Blackadder's Christmas Carol fits.
And here is the Wikipedia page.

Almost certain that this is it. The scene he described is exactly the one in Black Adder's Christmas Carol.

Except the twist is that Blackadder is a kind generous person, who is taken advantage of by everyone, and ends up giving away all his Christmas dinner, presents & money. Once the ghost shows him his ancestors, he decides to become a real bastard instead, unfortunately this coincides with Queen Victoria & Prince Albert visiting incognito.

@NiceOrc I think that qualifies as telling truth to power.
